# TCL list and foreach problem

Tags: list, foreach, tcl

Say I have a TCL list:

```
set myList {}
lappend myList [list a b 1]
lappend myList [list c d 2]
.....
```

Now I want to modify the list like this:

```
foreach item $myList {
lappend item "new"
}
```

But at the end I have not modified list. Why? item is a reference on the list item no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`item` is *not* a reference to the list item. It is a *copy*. To do what you want, you could do this:

```
set newlist {}
foreach item $myList {
  lappend item "new"
  lappend newlist $item
}
set mylist $newlist
```

Answer (score 2):

To edit the list “in place”, you can do this:

```
set idx -1
foreach item $myList {
    lappend item "new"
    lset myList [incr idx] $item
}
```

You can also do this if you've got Tcl 8.6 (notice that I'm not actually using `$item`; it's just convenient looping):

```
set idx -1
foreach item $myList {
    lset myList [incr idx] end+1 "new"
}
```

But it won't work on 8.5, where `lset` will only replace existing items (and sublists).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach item $myList {
    lappend item "new"
}
```

What you're doing here, is getting a variable (called item), and modifying it to also contain 'new'.  basically, you get lists that look like `{a new}`, `{b new}` and so on.  But you leak those variables at the end of each iteration.

What do you really want your list to look like when you're done?

Comment: I want to add a variable to the end of each sublist of my list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $myList]} {incr i} {
    set item [lindex $myList $i]
    lappend item new
    set myList [lreplace $myList $i $i $item]
}
```

If your list is very large, some efficiencies can be made (e.g. the [K combinator](http://wiki.tcl.tk/K)). They would just add complexity here.